# Preventing TlbImp from generating interop assemblies for referenced type libraries

Tags: tlbimp

I'm generating interop assemblies using `TlbImp`. Several of my type libraries reference a single core type library.

When I run `TlbImp` against `First.dll` I get `Interop.First.dll` and `Interop.Core.dll`. The problem is that when I run it again, against `Second.dll`, `TlbImp` tries to generate `Interop.Core.dll` again, resulting in the error:

```
TlbImp : error TI0000 : System.ApplicationException - The assembly for referenced
type library, 'Core', will not be imported since it would overwrite existing file
'Core.dll'.
```

How can I tell `TlbImp` not to generate interops for referenced assemblies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to use the [`/reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx) parameter to explicitly identify existing interop assemblies.

Originally I was running these commands:

```
> tlbimp Core.dll /out:Interop.Core.dll
> tlbimp First.dll /out:Interop.First.dll
> tlbimp Second.dll /out:Interop.Second.dll
```

`TlbImp` would try to import the referenced `Core.dll` and create an interop at `Core.dll` in the second and third commands, triggering an error.

To fix this, I just needed to explicitly specify the `Core` interop:

```
> tlbimp Core.dll /out:Interop.Core.dll
> tlbimp First.dll /reference:Interop.Core.dll /out:Interop.First.dll
> tlbimp Second.dll /reference:Interop.Core.dll /out:Interop.Second.dll
```